# Python how to comment out a for statement without unindenting

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, indentation

every time I am debugging a code that contains a for-loop e.g.

```
# When I debug this code

for i in range(3):
    print(i)
```

I come to want to fix a variable and execute the code, such as

```
# I want to do this

i = 2
# for i in range(3):
    print(i)
```

However, the above code **results in an error** because there is an unexpected indent. So I always have to unindent the lines inside the for-loop, which is repetitive work:

```
# But I have to do this

i = 2
# for i in range(3):
print(i)
```

### Question

Are there any ways to leave the indentation unchanged while commenting out the `for` line?

Comment: I usually replace this with `if True:`.  In similar but different scenarios, `pass` comes in helpful (e.g. you've commmented out the only line of a block, and an indent is expected)

Comment: Try indenting the line `i = 2` to the same level as `print(i)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the `for` loop with a block statement that executes the contents unconditionally:

```
i = 2
# for i in range(3):
if 1:  # Or if you prefer, if True:
    print(i)
```

Now the indent is expected, but since `if 1:`/`if True:` execute unconditionally (in Python 3, on the CPython reference interpreter, both of them optimize out the `if` completely; it executes without any sort of test), it behaves identically to the manually dedented version.

Alternatively, without adding an `i = 2` at all, you can make the `for` loop loop over a single constant value:

```
for i in [2]: # range(3): Old code
    print(i)
```

to get the same effect. `for i in (2,):` (parens optional) would also work, but that trailing comma that one-`tuple`s require messes a lot of people up, and as it happens, loops over `list`s of constant literals are optimized to loops over `tuple`s of constant literals anyway, so no performance loss is incurred.

Comment: Amazing! I should have asked much earlier! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `for` loop iterate over a single-item tuple instead:

```
for i in 2,:
# for i in range(3):
    print(i)
```